# Module of differential forms over the ring of smooth functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

I'm following Theodore Shifrin's course *Math 3510* on youtube. So I will use his notations.

If $\omega \in \Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ is an alternating multilinear map (i.e., a $k$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$) I visualize its geometrical meaning. Moreover since a $k$-form is a function, I know how to evaluate it on $k$ input vectors. For example if $\omega = 3dx \wedge dy + 5dx \wedge dz + 7dy \wedge dz = 3dx_{12} + 5dx_{13} + 7dx_{23}$ is a 2-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$ and $u = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2 \\ 11\end{pmatrix}$ then

$$
\omega(v,u) = 
3\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 5 \\ 
3 & 2 
\end{vmatrix}
+
5\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 5 \\ 
4 & 11 
\end{vmatrix}
+
7\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 2 \\ 
4 & 11 
\end{vmatrix} 
= 91
$$

Let $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the ring of smooth scalar functions from  $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
At the beginning of this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rci22jC_pS8) prof. Shifrin defines the set $\mathcal{A}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of differential $k$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the module over the ring $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ generated by $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$.
 An element of $\mathcal{A}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a sum $\eta = \sum_{I} f_Idx_I$ where each $I$ in the summation is a multi-index of cardinality $k$.

**How should I think about $\eta$ ? Can I look at $\eta$ as a function that takes vectors as inputs and returns a real number?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of it as taking $k$ smooth vector *fields* as inputs and returning a smooth function. So, if $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are vector fields, you'll have
$$\big(\eta(X_1,\dots,X_k)\big)(x) = \eta(x)(X_1(x),\dots,X_k(x)).$$
In particular, if $\eta = \sum f_I\,d\mathbf x_I$, you get the value $\sum f_I(x)\,d\mathbf x_I(X_1(x),\dots,X_k(x))$.

Comment: So if I understand well each vector field must have type $X_j: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ ($j=1, ..., k $) and each function coefficient has type $f_I: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ but $m$ may differ from $n$?

Comment: No, no, everything's $n$. Perhaps you want this happening on an open subset $U\subset\Bbb R^n$, but at each $x\in U$, you must end up with $X_i(x)$ in the tangent space of $U$ at $x$, which is, of course, $\Bbb R^n$. So, $f_I, X_i\colon U\to\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I think of $x$ ranging over the points of an $n$-dimensional surface $M$ (manifold). Then I imagine for each $x \in M$ the $k$ vector fields $X_j$ select $k$ vectors of the tangent space to $M$ at $x$ that define a $k$-dimensional "Euclidean  parallelogram" $P_x$. Each $d\mathbf{x}_I$ computes a $k$-dim oriented volume $V_I$ obtained by the projection of $P_x$ onto the coordinates $\mathbf{x}_I$ and finally the value given by the form at $x$ is the real number $\sum_I f_I(x)V_I$. So the $f_I$’s are volume scaling factors depending on the points of $M$? Are there clear physical examples?

Comment: Flux (of a vector field across a hypersurface) is the most natural. See, for example, [lecture 35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNy0ehstWBc&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=93&t=0s) in my lectures on YouTube.

Comment: During the course I’ve seen several times differential forms integrated over manifolds but I never see forms \emph{evaluated} and I’ve never seen in use the $k$ vector fields you mentioned. I’m puzzled about how the fact that forms are functions comes into play.

Comment: Is each of the vector fields $X_1,..., X_k$ intended to associate to each point $x$ of the manifold a vector of the orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$ ? So that for each $x$ the set $\{X_1(x),..., X_k(x)\}$ is a subset of the standard basis of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Absolutely NOT, @Alberto!! These formulas hold for arbitrary vectors and arbitrary vector fields.